# django Reverse for 'messages_inbox' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django

I have found some other posts on this topic, but they all seem to not work for me. I am getting this error while trying to use django_messages with djangobb_forum...

django_messages urls.py...

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='inbox/'), name='messages_redirect'),
    url(r'^inbox/$', inbox, name='messages_inbox'),
```

I have also put this in my djangobb_forum urls.py...

```
url(r'^messages/', include('django_messages.urls')),
```

and this is the template where it is trying to render...

```
<li id="navpm"><a href="{% url 'messages_inbox' %}">{% trans "PM" %}</a></li>
```

and here is the full traceback, I have been at this for hours and I cannot see what is happening...

```
nvironment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum/

Django Version: 1.8.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'main',
 'quiz',
 'study',
 'blog',
 'djangobb_forum',
 'pagination',
 'django_messages')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /home/jeff/Django/langalang/langalang/djangobb_forum/templates/djangobb_forum/header.html, error at line 24
   Reverse for 'messages_inbox' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

   14 :             {% block menu %}



   15 :                 <li id="navindex"><a href="{% url 'djangobb:index' %}">{% trans "Index" %}</a></li>



   16 :                 <li id="navuserlist"><a href="{% url 'djangobb:forum_users' %}">{% trans "User list" %}</a></li>



   17 :                 <li id="navsearch"><a href="{% url 'djangobb:search' %}">{% trans "Search" %}</a></li>



   18 :                 {% if user.is_superuser %}



   19 :                     <li id="navadmin"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans "Administration" %}</a></li>



   20 :                 {% endif %}



   21 :                 {% if user.is_authenticated %}



   22 :                     <li id="navprofile"><a href="{% url 'djangobb:forum_profile' user.username %}">{% trans "Profile" %}</a></li>



   23 :                     {% if forum_settings.PM_SUPPORT %}



   24 :                         <li id="navpm"><a href=" {% url 'messages_inbox' %} ">{% trans "PM" %}</a></li> 



   25 :                     {% endif %}



   26 :                 {% endif %}



   27 :             {% endblock %}



   28 :             </ul>



   29 :         </div>



   30 :         <div id="brdwelcome" class="inbox">



   31 :             <ul class="conl">



   32 :                 {% if user.is_authenticated %}



   33 :                     <li>{% trans "Logged in as" %} <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong></li>



   34 :                     <li>{% trans "Last visit:" %} {% forum_time user.last_login %}</li>


Traceback:
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/langalang/djangobb_forum/views.py" in index
  80.         return render(request, 'djangobb_forum/index.html', to_return)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  99.         return template.render(context, request)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  74.         return self.template.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                     return self._render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  135.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  40.         output = self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  65.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  159.                 return template.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  211.                 return self._render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  201.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  56.                 result = self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  329.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  903.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  79.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  507.                         six.reraise(*exc_info)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  493.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  579.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/pyenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  496.                              (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /forum/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'messages_inbox' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

EDIT: Adding the line that includes djangobb_forum...

```
url(r'^forum/', include('djangobb_forum.urls', namespace='djangobb')),
url(r'^(?P<page_lang>\w+)/forum/', include('djangobb_forum.urls', namespace='djangobb')),
```

Comment: Can you show the line that includes django_bb_forum/urls.py into the main urls.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including the djangobb_forum urls with a namespace, and since your django_messages urls are themselves included within the other, you need the namespace there too.

```
<a href="{% url 'djangobb:messages_inbox' %}">
```

I'm not sure that's what you meant to do though; you should probably include the django_messages urls directly into the main urls.py.